# bash for loop behaves differently when the arguments positions are changed

Tags: bash, for-loop

Checking in `bash` `for` loop with changing the last two arguments' positions.

Below code prints:

```
$ for ((i=1;i<2;i++)); do echo $i; done   
1
```

But below code prints all the natural numbers that I can see:

```
$ for ((i=1;i++;i<2)); do echo $i; done   
1    
2   
3   
4    
5 
6
.
.
.
```

What is the reason for that?

Comment: That's not just bash -- it's true for C, and Java, and every other language that has this `for` syntax. The three statements have three different positions, which are invoked at different times.

Comment: Do you have any documentation you could reference to explain why you have the contrary expectation?

Comment: The second position is the condition, whether or not you provide a boolean expression. Likewise, the third position is evaluated solely for its side effect, whether or not it has one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's `man bash`:

```
   for (( expr1 ; expr2 ; expr3 )) ; do list ; done
          First, the arithmetic expression expr1 is evaluated according to
          the  rules  described  below  under  ARITHMETIC EVALUATION.  The
          arithmetic expression expr2 is then evaluated  repeatedly  until
          it  evaluates  to zero.  Each time expr2 evaluates to a non-zero
          value, list is executed and the arithmetic expression  expr3  is
          evaluated.   If  any  expression is omitted, it behaves as if it
          evaluates to 1.  The return value is the exit status of the last
          command in list that is executed, or false if any of the expres‐
          sions is invalid.
```

Note especially:

> Each time expr2 evaluates to a non-zero value, list is executed and the arithmetic expression  expr3  is evaluated.

`expr2` , `i++`, in your case will not evaluate to 0 until the integer wraps around after `2^64 = 18446744073709551616` iterations.

`expr3`, `i<2`, will evaluate to 0 after the first iteration, but as you can see from the description, this has no effect on anything.